# PLSQL select %rowtype while reading .txt file does exit loop

Tags: plsql

Working on a procedure which reads a file, line by line until no data found.
The .txt file contains shopdetails, so each line is a detail.

e.g

```
naam: Delfzijl
straat: De Wending 
huisnr: 7
postcode: 9933KM
plaats: delfzijl 
land: NL 
telnr: 0596743101

naam: Groningen Boterdiep
straat: Boterdiep
huisnr: 1
postcode: 9712LH
plaats: GRONINGEN
land: NL
telnr: 0505266600

naam: Groningen Paddepoel
straat: Zonnelaan
huisnr: 281A
postcode: 9742BG
plaats: GRONINGEN
land: NL
telnr: 0505710012
etc..
```

After checking the details, those should be inserted into an table.

Now the problem I have is by checking the details.

For example I need to check if the 'postcode' (zipcode) is known from an other table. I simply use an select into query inside the loop, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_heeft_postcode
FROM postcode
WHERE postcode = v_postcode; 

-- postcode check  
IF v_heeft_postcode = 0 THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zipcode shop ' || v_naam || ' is unknown.');
END IF;
```

outputs:

```
naam: Emmen
straat: Spoorstraat
huisnr: 6
postcode: 7811GC
plaats: EMMEN
land: NL
telnr: 0591724400
Zipcode shop Emmen is unknown.
```

This seems to work, it outputs for each shop if the zipcode is unknow.
The strange problem I have is: if i select an entire row, my loop will exit after the fist shop, instead of looping throw the entire .txt file

```
SELECT * INTO v_postcode_row
FROM postcode
WHERE postcode = v_postcode;
```

Outputs: once 1 set of details (1shop)

the loop i use:

```
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      UTL_FILE.GET_LINE( f_text, v_bestand_lijn );
      -- getting shop details line by line
      -- name 
      IF v_counter = 1 THEN
        v_naam := v_bestand_lijn;
        v_counter := v_counter + 1;
      -- street
      ELSIF v_counter = 2 THEN
        v_straat := v_bestand_lijn;
        v_counter := v_counter + 1;
      -- house number
      ELSIF v_counter = 3 THEN
        v_huis_nr := v_bestand_lijn;
        v_counter := v_counter + 1;
      -- city
      ELSIF v_counter = 4 THEN
        v_plaats := v_bestand_lijn;
        v_counter := v_counter + 1;
      -- county
      ELSIF v_counter = 5 THEN
         v_land := v_bestand_lijn;
         v_counter := v_counter + 1;
      -- zipcode
      ELSIF v_counter = 6 THEN
         v_postcode := v_bestand_lijn;
         v_counter := v_counter + 1;
      -- tel number
      ELSIF v_counter = 7 THEN
         v_tel_nr := v_bestand_lijn;
         v_counter := v_counter + 1;

      -- empty line between shop details
      ELSIF v_counter = 8 THEN

      -- showing details
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'naam: ' || v_naam );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'straat: ' || v_straat);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'huisnr: ' || v_huis_nr );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'postcode: ' || v_postcode );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'plaats: ' || v_plaats );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'land: ' || v_land );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'telnr: ' || v_tel_nr );

      -- zipcode check (working for each shop)
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_heeft_postcode
      FROM postcode
      WHERE postcode = v_postcode;

      -- showing message by unknown zipcode
      IF v_heeft_postcode = 0 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zipcode shop ' || v_naam || ' is unknown.');
      END IF;

      -- housnr check (by using %rowtype like this, it will exit the loop for some strange reason)
      -- SELECT * INTO v_postcode_row
      -- FROM postcode
      -- WHERE postcode = v_postcode;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '' ); 
      v_counter := 1;
      END IF; 

    EXCEPTION WHEN No_Data_Found THEN EXIT; 
  END;
END LOOP;
```

So, the select by COUNT(*) will loop though the hole file, line by line and shows a message if zipcode isn't found, and the select into rowtype is only showing 1 shop (only 1 time loop). I can't figure out why,, already searching for like hours so you can really help me out here. Thanks!

**additional explanation by screenshots**

select count will check for each time loop
[image]

select %rowtype will exit loop after first shop
[image]

Comment: Does the postcode exist? The last line of code I can see says "Exception when no_data_found then exit;"

Comment: yes it does! It's really strange because when i use select count(*) with the same where value (v_postcode), it will run though the entire file, but when i use a rowtype (same where postcode=v_postcode) it will exit on the first one..

Comment: But does the count() return 0? Count() does not raise a no_data_found exception, where as using a rowtype will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is being caused by the fact that using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_heeft_postcode
FROM postcode
WHERE postcode = v_postcode;
```

sets v_heeft_postcode to 0 when the postcode does not exist, whereas:

```
SELECT * INTO v_postcode_row
FROM postcode
WHERE postcode = v_postcode;
```

will raise a no_data_found exception when the postcode does not exist.

Instead of exiting the procedure, you could instead change your exception handler to do the following:

```
Exception when no_data_found then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Zipcode shop ' || v_naam || ' is unknown.');
```

I'm pretty sure that should make both pieces of code function the same way.

Comment: Woo big thanks for response! This was indeed the issue.